# How do I check if AlarmManager has an alarm set with FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

If I create a PendingIntent with FLAG_ONE_SHOT, a subsequent PendingIntent with FLAG_NO_CREATE returns null.

```
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context,this.getId(),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ON_SHOT);
    GregorianCalendar alarmtime = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR),now.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH),now.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0);

    //Set the alarm
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmtime.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    } else {
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmtime.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
    }

    //Now check if the alarm was set, if it was set, the following PendingIntent should return not null but it doesn't
    PendingIntent piCheck = PendingIntent.getService(context,this.getId(),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    if (piCheck!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"piCheck returned NOT NULL and probably returned pi");
    } else if (piCheck==null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"piCheck returned NULL pi does not exist");
```

However if I change the first pending intent to:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context,this.getId(),intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Then my second PendingIntent returns not null as expected.

Both PendingIntents set an alarm properly, but I cannot "check" the FLAG_ONE_SHOT PendingIntent. What is the reason for this behaviour? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: I think you must be confused. What makes you think that calling `getService()` with flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` should return `null`? It will only return `null` if the `PendingIntent` doesn't exist. However, you have just previously created the `PendingIntent`, so of course it still exists. I've no idea why it returns `null` if you use flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` because that also creates a new `PendingIntent`. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry mixed up my null and not null. With FLAG_NO_CREATE it IS returning null even though the PendingIntent exists. FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT works as expected.

Comment: I still think you are confused. If you create a `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` this `PendingIntent can only be used once. Once it is used, it will be deleted. Specifying `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` will never return `null`, as it will **always** create a new `PendingIntent`.

Comment: But after either PendingIntent is created I would have though a PI with FLAG_NO_CREATE should return that PI if it exists correct? But it only returns the FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT PI, it never returns the ONE_SHOT PI (it returns null instead). That to me indicates that PI doesn't exist. But it does. It was created with ONE_SHOT but it still exists...am I making sense?

Comment: I'll need to test this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small test program to verify this behaviour. If you create a `PendingIntent` using `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` and then pass this to the `AlarmManager`, it looks like Android "consumes" the `PendingIntent` immediately so that it no longer exists (because it is a "one-shot", it can only be used once). I would have thought this would happen when the alarm actually triggers, but it looks like that isn't the case.

You learn something new every day :-)

To solve your problem, I would just remove the `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` as you probably don't need it (just pass `0` as the "flags" argument). If you set the alarm more than once, you can use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` if you set the alarm with different extras each time (but it looks like you aren't using any extras, so you probably don't need this). I don't think that you need `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here arises because `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` *describes* the `PendingIntent` and so will be needed to identify it.

You can check for its existence by using `FLAG_ONE_SHOT | FLAG_NO_CREATE`. 
Your code snippet is essentially checking for a different `PendingIntent` (one without `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`) which doesn't exist and hence you get `null`.

You can also try this out with `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` which is another flag that describes the requested `PendingIntent`.

I don't think that alarms are involved.