# PendingIntent FLAG_NO_CREATE with different Context

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-context, android-pendingintent

Ok, I have next method:

```
private boolean isPresentPengingIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getService(context,0,myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
}
```

`myIntent` is always the same.

I'm wondering - if I pass different `context` into this method, it returns **false**.

But if I plan new `Alarm` with:

```
PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

(also with different `context`) - it will erase previous alarm (because `myIntent` is the same, that's why `PendingIntent` is considering the same).

Why there is a different behaviour due to `context`?
**Is there a way** to ignore `context` parameter in my `isPresentPengingIntent` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context` is not your problem. What you are seeing is a strangeness in the way `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` works.

You cannot determine if a `PendingIntent` exists or not using your code if you have created the `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`. As far as Android is concerned, this `PendingIntent` does not exist.

If you want to determine whether or not an alarm is set by using the existing of the `PendingIntent` as an indicator, then you cannot use `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763646/how-do-i-check-if-alarmmanager-has-an-alarm-set-with-flag-one-shot/27838622#27838622